# Is there a way to get Flutter app to take scrolling screenshots?

Tags: android, flutter, screenshot

I've tried to take scrolling screenshots on my Flutter app similar to how it is done on other apps but so far it has not been possible.

From what I've researched, it seems that Android has a hard time figuring out if a screen is scrollable on a Flutter app compared to a native app and that is what is causing the issue. Does anyone know a workaround for this?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.